# How to have buttons persist through views while maintaining same functionality

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, design-patterns

I'm just getting into ios development and I'm wondering how to accomplish this.

Say for example I have 3 screens - I want each of those screens to have the same 1 button that links to the same place whether you tap it on screen 1 2 or 3.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having a separate method for each view controller?

Also if a solution is too much to type out, are there any good references/guides I can look at for this?

---

Edit: Another example in case it is a bit confusing - having a login button in the same position across 5 different screens that all take you to the same login screen

Comment: There are many options for how you might accomplish this. You should give more details about how your project is set up. For instance, are you using a storyboard, or creating these view controllers in code? Do you want to present the new (login) view controller modally or push it onto the navigation controller? My first instinct is that you should probably have 3 different methods, but that these methods might call the same method to switch to the login viewController.

Comment: Try reading a bit about container view controllers and see if that works for you.  Basically, one controller looks after the common elements and provides a space for the contained controllers to display their content.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: @livingtech Thanks for the response. I'm using story boards and I'm not too sure how segues work just yet but I'm trying to get an idea of how this will work. Because I will have about 15 screens and they will all share the same 6 buttons or so. So I was wondering if I'd have to create 15 separate methods and link all 6 to each one or what.

Comment: If you are just moving between view controllers in your storyboard... do you know about CTRL-dragging from the button to the view controller? No code is needed to initiate a push or modal presentation.

Answer (score 0):

> having a login button in the same position across 5 different screens that all take you to the same login screen

Why not have all these login buttons be instances of the same UIButton subclass? You subclass once, and you configure your subclass so that it sets its own frame (position) and so that tapping the button calls code within itself. Presto, a completely self-contained button, looking and behaving identically wherever it appears.

Another solution to the problem of calling common code when tapped would a button with a nil-targeted action. This means that the tap causes a search up the responder chain. So your response code could live in, say, the app delegate, and the nil-targeted action would find it.

Comment: @Cristik On the contrary, a nil-targeted action is completely uncoupled. That's the point.

Comment: @Cristik Then you do not know far enough. :)

Comment: @Cristik and in any case it's only an example. It could go anywhere up the responder chain. But clearly it good not go in any view controller, because each instance of the OP's button is ultimately governed by a different view controller. Personally I'm not saying either of these is the best solution. I'm just telling the OP there are some solutions.